# Google Sheets: Empty Cell is not "Empty"

Tags: sorting, filter, google-sheets

Here's the thing,

[image]

there's an empty cell in a list by using `=""`

and I have sheets full of this kind of "empty text" because of an `=IF(this happens,A, "")`, and so when I sort it using `=SORT()`, it becomes like this:

[image]

The empty cell gets treated as a text and is the first in the list
check image: Notice that I selected B5.

The general solution would be to use `=SORT(Filter(range, range>""), ... , ... )` and it did the job so far - but now I'm trying to do something like `=SORT(FILTER(formula_generated_range, ??? , ??? ), ... , ... )` and I don't know how to write the `???` part of that and so I can't get rid of the empty cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of the following formulas:

```
=sort(arrayformula(if(len(A5:A9),A5:A9,)),1,true)
```

```
=sort(filter(A5:A9,len(A5:A9)),1,true)
```

```
=query(A5:A9,"select A where A<>'' order by A")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an evaluation of a range you can also feed the formula filter a logical array with the same length.

You can thus feed it either the exact same arrayformula IF that you use to generate the data range **or** you simplify it to be TRUE or FALSE by checking just for the rejection criterion.

Imagine the following:

```
A    B    B (Formula)
1    21   =ArrayFormula(SORT(FILTER(IF(A1:A6 > 20, A1:A6, ""), A1:A6 > 20)))
100  100
2    510
510
21
```